# Does onreadystatechange == complete fire after CSSOM is loaded?

Tags: javascript, dom, onreadystatechange, cssom

The question is small and simple:

Does `onreadystatechange == complete` fire after CSSOM is loaded?

Please mention some authorotative reference in your answer so I could cross check. Thanks :-)